# OOP; Class containing data

Tags: oop

This isn't really a serious OOP question, just want to get an opinion on the best way to take for my program.

Simple really: Let's say I have an employee class, and that class has the variables and methods that make up an employee.

My question is how would I store an 'employee data'(Data, not Object); It IS SIMPLE, I could just make a JOHN class that extends EMPLOYEE and add data there.

But I've read(actually not sure where) storing simple data in classes is not good?? Because if you extend a class, you should also add other functions in it.

Is there a disadvantage in the solution I proposed? Or is there a better way to 'store' data. NOTE: Assume I cannot open external files and I must add whatever Data I have in the code.

Answer (score 2):

OK:

1) A "class" is a "template" for creating "objects".

A class doesn't contain any data - a class *instance* (a.k.a. an "object") contains data.

2) An instance of "Employee" might be an object with a member name (member data) of "John".

You wouldn't "extend" Employee to create "John"; you'd create an "object" with the name "John".

3) You might, however, extend employee for a "Manager" class.

4) To answer your original question, *of course* a "class" can be designed to hold "data".  And every *object* of that class will contain that data.

Comment: Well that's the thing, I need to create an actual class that has data, and I'm going to create instances of that class (Might seem counter intuitive but I do infact need multiple JOHNs.)

Comment: As I tried to say above: storing data in classes is good.  Honest :)